# 403 Forbidden on GET to Calendar that I have delegate access to

Tags: api, graph, outlook, office365

I have been delegated access to an Outlook calendar.  I received the sharing invite and accepted it.  I have been given read\write access.  When I do a GET on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars, I get both mine and the shared calendar listed.  However, when I try to GET /users/{user principal}/calendar, I get access denied.  There is a banner in the Graph Explorer showing "Forbidden - 403 - 381ms. You need to consent to the permissions on the Modify permissions tab", but the Modify permissions tab is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem at:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer-v4/issues/603

The permissions are listed on your profile settings.